# PHP: limit the scope of functions to within current file only

Tags: php, function, scope

Is there any way to limit the scope of non-class functions in a php file and making them the only accessible within the php file it is located in? Like how C can achieve this using static keyword with functions. In php static seems to be for classes only. I want to hide helper functions that should only be accessed by functions within the file. Thanks.

Comment: Only write the functions in that file?

Comment: Function from one file is accessible from another file if the other file is run later

Answer (score 2):

The closest solution I can figure out is this:

```
<?php
call_user_func( function() {
    //functions you don't want to expose
    $sfunc = function() {
        echo 'sfunc' . PHP_EOL;
    };

    //functions you want to expose
    global $func;
    $func = function() use ($sfunc) {
        $sfunc();
        echo 'func' . PHP_EOL;
    }; 
} );

$func();
?>
```

But you have to call the functions like `$func()` instead of `func()`. The problem is that it breaks when you re-assign `$func` to other value.

```
$func = 'some other value';
$func();  //fails
```

Of course you can create wrapper functions:

```
function func() {
    $func();
}
```

In this way you can call it like `func()`, but the re-assigning problem still exists:

```
$func = 'some other value';
func();  //fails
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's an interesting way of implementing it. However, like you said it will break and down and can get over complicated. I was hoping for something in built in php but I guess it is not possible, nor did the developers find it important to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer the OOP way to hide something in PHP.